# what is the best practice in this case?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have a form and there is a special field for upload CV despite name,lastname
and i am resolving it like this:

```
 const handleChange = (event) =>{
        const value = event.target.name === "cv" ? event.target.files[0] : event.target.value;
        const name = event.target.name;
        setJobForm((prev)=>{
          return {...prev,[name]:value}
        })
    }
```

the state of each field:

```
const [jobForm,setJobForm] = useState({
    name:'',
    lastname:'',
    day:'',
    month:'',
    year:'',
    phone:'',
    email:'',
    jobPosition:'',
    coments:'',
    cv:[]
})
```

the error i get when i upload a pdf file is:
why this is happening??

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to set the 'value' property on
> 'HTMLInputElement': This input element accepts a filename, which may
> only be programmatically set to the empty string.

Comment: You cannot set the value of a "file" input element, and your code is attempting to do that (indirectly).

Answer (score 0):

```
const handleChange = (event) => {
  const { name, value, files } = event.target;
  if (name === "cv") {
    const cvFile = files[0];
    setJobForm((prev) => ({ ...prev, cv: cvFile }));
  } else {
    setJobForm((prev) => ({ ...prev, [name]: value }));
  }
};
```

Comment: Hello , thank you, but i have fixed it even better,
    const handleChange = (event) =>{
        const value = event.target.name === "cv" ? event.target.files[0] : event.target.value;
        const name = event.target.name;
        setJobForm((prev)=>{
          return {...prev,[name]:value}
        })
    }